# How to replace AsynTask with RxJava in this case

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-asynctask, rx-java2

I have a class that goes to decrease the image but I'm currently on AsyncTask, now I want to replace it because AsyncTask is now deprecated.So can someone help me out with a workaround

Here is my code:

```
class DecreaseImageTask(
    val uri: Uri? = null,
    val bitmap: Bitmap? = null,
    var context: Context,
    var listener: (String?) -> Unit
) : AsyncTask<Void, Long, String?>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
        return when {
            uri != null -> {
                decreaseImageSize(imagePath = FileUtils.getPathURI(context, uri) ?: "")
            }
            bitmap != null -> {
                decreaseImageSize(bitmap = bitmap)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        listener(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `decreaseImageSize` to accept a callback as a parameter.
In this case, the function will no longer need to return a string, which is passed as a parameter to the callback function and then used as
a parameter in its body:

```
fun decreaseImageSize(imagePath: String? = null, bitmap: Bitmap? = null, callback: (String) -> Unit) {
    ...

    val result = "" // The result of the previous decreaseImageSize function

    callback(result)
}
```

Then, instead of calling the `AsyncTask` use the new `decreaseImageSize` function:

```
    decreaseImageSize(imagePath = FileUtils.getPathURI(context, uri) ?: "") { result -> 
        // Execute the code after the image is decreased
    }

    decreaseImageSize(bitmap = bitmap) { result -> 
        // Execute the code after the image is decreased
    }
```